# Regex: recursive backreferences - what for?

Tags: regex, recursion, capture, backreference

I found some interesting possibility in many regex engines:

*It's possible to place backreference inside the capture group and reference this group.*

For example: `(\1)`

My question: for what regex patterns it may be used? I can't imagine...

Comment: if you need to find out index of the second occurrence?

Comment: SilentGhost, you should've posted that as an answer.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I believe that should be an answer.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to using a reference inside the capture group where the reference is defined (e.g. `a(b\1c)d`), I don't know of any engines that support that - care to give an example? Not that I see any possible meaning for it either.

Comment: Yes, you understand me, Max S =) For example, .NET regex engine supports that behavior. I'm trying to find where such patterns may be useful...

Comment: (@Brad, no, he said the backref _inside_ the capture group.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [explanation for use of nested references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#invalid), which I think clearly demonstrates the marginal usefulness of this feature.

Comment: If you sloooowly read my question, you'll understand that I'm not asking about how backreferences are used normally. Take a look WHERE backreference were placed in the example regex I provide.

Comment: @ControlFlow: I don't see you posting *any* regex. I can't imagine what `(\1)`  could possibly match or be useful for, or even compile. is this question limited to .net? if not, do provide us with some actual examples.

Comment: `(\1)` does compile on .NET, but I am yet to find any possible use for it.

Comment: The `(\1)` regex was the minimal example, not useful at all, just to demonstrate what I'm talking about. Thanks for the link, I've expecting the usefullness... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've got a long yaml schema, which I need/want to change from this:

```
columns:
    id:
      type: string(36)
      fixed: true
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    descripcion:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

To this:

```
columns:
    id: {type: string(36), fixed: true, unsigned: false, primary: true, autoincrement: false}
    descripcion: {...}...
```

in this case I need a level of recursion in backrefences, because the column names are in between column description.
This is suitable for each line, but i cant put "{}" arround $1, I'd end up with brackets between each description field:

```
"\n^      ([^\n]+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (ignore the whitespace):

`{ .* ( { .* \1 .* } ) .* }`

to match the body of a method in C#/Java/...

Comment: It will not work, backreference matches with the capture group 1 matched text, not the pattern in the group 1 itself.

Comment: @ControlFlow: That merely needs to be `(?1)` instead of `\1`, and it will indeed recurse on decent regex engines.